# Using Flow Builder, how do I add a chatter post to a case using a service account?

Tags: lightning

I have a flow that adds a post to a case feed when the criteria are met.

The Feed items appear as posted by me. I would prefer that they show as posted by our service account.

How do I set up the flow to do that?

Thanks much,
Steve

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for the information so far, but you need to please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/359774/edit) your question to also add information. *(From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Your question should include... (the code, metadata, or design, in its current form). and/or the research and work you’ve done so far on the issue. ")* Why do they appear to as posted by you? Who are you (your role) in relation to this Flow? What have you attempted so far to change it?

Comment: generate a platform event that is consumed by a trigger that has a context user of your service account, the trigger then does the post